# Why does this code keep refreshing in an endless loop?

Tags: apex

I am trying to put the user in edit mode with a specific recordtype. If I paste the URL below in a browser it works. When do this it keeps trying to access the page as in an endless loop.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Proposal__c"action="{!silentRedirect}" showHeader="false">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://eu3.salesforce.com/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried using Apex like this which is called from a VF page. Same issue.

```
public class vf_HiddenRedirect {

public vf_HiddenRedirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{

}

public pageReference silentRedirect()
{ 
    Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.severity.INFO, 'silentRedirect'));

    String url = 'https://eu3.salesforce.com/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9';

    //'/apex/vf_sendCancel_Voucher_byEmail?oppId='+oppIDlocal + '&ButtonClicked=CancelVoucherIndividually' + '&FlMngr='+ FlMngrId + '&FlightIdlist=' + flightToBecancelledString;

    Pagereference pr = new PageReference(url);
    pr.setRedirect(true);

   return pr;

}
```

}

Why is it doing it and how to have just how the intended page?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need that meta tag?

Comment: It's a simple HTML tag that redirects a page to a give URL. Do you have a better way?

Comment: Try using a small javascript snippet to redirect the page, and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b try to use action method without meta tag. It should work without infinite loop